# kotlin upload image by retrofit

Tags: php, android, kotlin, file-upload, retrofit2

I want to select an image from gallery and upload it to server by retrofit.
but when I upload image The answer that returns is unsuccessful and reason is:(No such file or directory)
I think my server code has some problem too,please check and help me
this is my codes:

my apiservice:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("upload.php")
    fun uploadImage(@Part filePart:MultipartBody.Part):Call<Message>
```

fragment code:

```
    image.setOnClickListener {
                var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1001)
            }

 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1001 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            image.setImageURI(data!!.data)
            var file = File(data!!.data!!.path)
            var requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file)
            var filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload_file", file.name, requestBody)
            viewModel.uploadImage(filePart).observe(this, Observer {
                Toast.makeText(context, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })

        }
    }
```

and the server code:

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
//if(isset($_FILES['upload_file'])) {

    $target_dir = "/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . microtime().rand(99999,999999).basename($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo '{"status":"error","message":"فایل معتبر نیست"}';
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }


// Check file size
    if ($_FILES["upload_file"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo '{"status":"error","message":"حجم عکس نباید بیشتر از 500 کیلوبایت باشد"}';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
// Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
         ) {
        echo '{"status":"error","message":"فرمت عکس اشتباه است"}';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo '{"status":"error","message":"متاسفانه عکس آپلود نشد"}';
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], SITE_ROOT.$target_file)) {
            echo '{"status":"success","message":"عکس با موفقیت آپلود شد"}';
        } else {
            echo '{"status":"error","message":"مشکل در آپلود فایل"}';
        }
    //}
}
```

Comment: _“No such file or directory”_ - so you specified a wrong path somewhere then … Go check what file and line number the error message mentions, check what path you are actually using in that place, and … _correct it_.

Comment: @04FS I have no crash,this is upload onfailure error

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say by that. I assumed that by _“and reason is:(No such file or directory)”_ you were referring to an actual PHP error message stating that. If that’s not it - then _properly_ explain what you get where and when.

Comment: @04FS This message occurs after the upload.I debugged and see retrofit onfailure called instead of onsuccess.I tried it in postman and did not work true.if I use a html form and try to upload an image every thing is ok but when clear html tags and use postman it does not work truely

Comment: Is that supposed to be the full message? Or does it mention a file and line number, as PHP messages do?

Comment: @04FS  I fully explained whether you understood what I meant?

Answer (score 0):

I had come across the same issue few months ago. Not sure but the newer versions of Android do not give you the path for the image selected. Try sending your selected image as ByteArray and see if it works out for you. Here is a snippet you can follow.

replace "image" with the param value you are passing as form data.Also let filePartImage be of type MultipartBody.Part . Then send this filePartImage var as param in your api call. Hope it works for you !

```
if (requestCode == UPLOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {

            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, data.data)
            product_iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

            val imageType = contentResolver.getType(data.data!!)

            val extension = imageType!!.substring(imageType.indexOf("/") + 1)

            data.data!!.let {
                application.contentResolver.openInputStream(it)?.use { inputStream ->
                    filePartImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                        "image",
                        "image.$extension",
                        inputStream.readBytes().toRequestBody("*/*".toMediaType())
                    )
                }
            }
            showMessage(this, "" + getString(R.string.image_uploaded))
        } else {
            showMessage(this, "" + getString(R.string.image_failed))
        }
    }
```